# Bootstrap - navbar-fixed-top inside another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with `width:500px` and `height:300px` in the middle of a page.
I want **inside** this div to have my navbar-fixed-top.
Can you please correct my html/css to accomplish that?
Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7874/

```
<div class="container" style="width:500px;height:300px;border:solid black 1px;overflow:scroll">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-inner" style="padding:10px">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="height:70px;" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <div class="icon-some"></div>Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>

                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p>some content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="padding-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on what you said you want the nav bar with the class navbar-fixed-top to be inside the div, it seems simple enough.

All I did was add a position:relative to the css file for the .navbar class

```
.navbar{
 position:relative;
}
```

Here is it working

http://jsfiddle.net/tKCm6/

Now if you wanted the nav to stay fixed in the div as you scroll down the page thats a different story.

Here is the code for that

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
}
.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    width:500px;
}
```

and live

http://jsfiddle.net/vARTv/